# Recomendación sobre versiones Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, control-de-versiones

Buen día estimados. Mi consulta es la siguiente.
Actualmente me encuentro realizando desarrollos usando **Laravel, Vue** y Angular para otros proyectos.
Mi pregunta es relacionada a la versión que debo usar.
Me gusta mucho la versión **5.5** de **Laravel**.
Es con la que mayor cantidad de proyectos tengo por ser muy fácil manejable en cuanto al **UI**.
Si bien es cierto ya existe la **versión 8**, ¿es buena practica seguir usando esa versión?.
Como desarrollador me gusta seguir mucho las buenas practicas a la hora de programar.
Sabre apreciar una orientación para saber si estoy haciendo mal o no.
Muchas Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tu pregunta aunque interesante es totalmente basada en opiniones, si lees [el *release notes*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/releases) la versión que usas ya no tiene soporte sobre posibles bugs o temas de seguridad, entonces tal vez te conviene moverte a Laravel 6 [aqui puedes leer hasta cuando tendrá soporte](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/releases). Te menciono que es basada en opiniones y terminará cerrada por que habrá quien te diga como yo, muévete a la v. 6 y otros que directo a la 8

Comment: Si bien la pregunta esta basada en opiniones hay una cosa que es cierta, ya no tiene soporte. Toma el ejemplo de windows 7 y windows 10. Ya tu decidiras con que trabajar

Answer (score 1):

En la mayoría de frameworks encontraremos una versión llamada LTS, esta es la versión recomendada para utilizar en producción cuando se necesita robustez, aunque claro, esta versión no suele tener las ultimas características y novedades ya que generalmente no es la versión más actual.

**¿Que es LTS?**

El soporte a largo plazo (en inglés, Long Term Support, abreviadamente, LTS) es un término informático usado para nombrar versiones o ediciones especiales de software diseñadas para tener soportes durante un período más largo que el normal.

*Definición referencial de [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soporte_de_largo_plazo)*

**¿Qué nos dice laravel de LTS?**

Para las versiones LTS, como Laravel 6, las correcciones de errores se proporcionan durante 2 años y las correcciones de seguridad durante 3 años. Estas versiones proporcionan la ventana más larga de soporte y mantenimiento. Para las versiones generales, se proporcionan correcciones de errores durante 7 meses y las correcciones de seguridad durante 1 año. Para todas las bibliotecas adicionales, incluida Lumen, solo la última versión recibe correcciones de errores.

*Referencia a la [documentación de laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases)*

**Conclusión**

Una versión LTS tiene más soporte que una versión normal, esto sumado a que no tiene nuevas características hace que los errores de la versión LTS disminuyan, se encuentren en su mayoría solucionados y por ende sea una versión más "estable" en comparación a otras, lo que lo hace ideal para llevar a producción.

Por otro lado, lo malo de las versiones LTS es que carecen de nuevas funcionalidades y características.

Ahora viene la parte basada en opiniones ¿Estabilidad o ultimas características? bueno, eso lo decides tú según tus necesidades.

> A día de hoy, 21-12-2020 la versión LTS de laravel es 6 (LTS)